# TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of null

Tags: node.js, api, express, postman

**Here is the admin route which gives the above error everytime I try to check the login functioning using Postman, I am new to NodeJS, so please help.**

```
const express = require('express');
const Admin = require('../models/admin');

const router = express.Router();

router.post('', (req, res, next) => {
    Admin.findOne({ email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password })
        .then(Admin => {
            if (req.body.email == Admin.email) {
                res.status(200).json({
                    message: 'Admin allowed!'
                 });
            }
            else{
                res.status(401).json({
                    message: 'Unauthorized!'
                })
            }
            
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('error: ', err);
        })
    })

    
module.exports = router;
```

[image]

**app.js(main file)**

```
 const adminRoutes = require('./routes/admin');
    app.use('/api/admin', adminRoutes);

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Can you show us how did you use the exported router in the main file?

Comment: I've edited it. You can check.

Comment: Express on its own doesn't have a middleware to parse form-data format. You can change the request to JSON format like Fabio's recommendation. You also need to use [`express.json()` middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html). Also, is there any middleware before the `post` route?

Answer (score 1):

You have more problems:

- To parse request body you need to install [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)
- Wrong route path declared `router.post('', ...`. From screenshot I see the path `router.post('/api/admin', ...`
- You set name for result as model name `.then(Admin => {`. It's wrong. You need to set a different variable name `.then((user) => {`
- You try to check if is email same from body and model, but this check mongo do it when you call `.findOne()`.

Here is an example of how implement a express api route:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Admin = require('../models/admin');

const app = express();

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

         // here you define path
app.post('/api/admin', async (req, res) => {

    try {
        
                      // mongo db query
        const admin = await Admin.findOne({ email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password });
        // check if have data
        if (!admin) {
            res.status(401).json({
                message: 'Unauthorized!'
            });
        }

        res.status(200).json({
            message: 'Admin allowed!'
        });

    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).json({
            error: e
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using form-data. Try to use in body => raw => json:

{
"email": "something@something",
"password": "something"
}

Comment: Still the issue is same :(

Comment: Could you post the output of the req.body ?